# Desserializar JSON com null safety em C#

Tags: c#

Um pouco de contexto:

Possuo um projeto em C# 8 utilizando um recurso chamado *Nullable Reference Types*. Quando esse recurso é ativado nas configurações do projeto (*csproj*) o compilador trata todas as instancias de classes como não-anuláveis, a menos que sejam declaradas como anuláveis explicitamente.

Por exemplo:

```cs
string  str1 = null; // isso é inválido
string? str2 = null; // isso é válido
```

Porém notei que esse recurso existe apenas em tempo de compilação, se a variável do tipo `string` for inicializada por um código externo, ela ainda pode receber o valor `null` em tempo de execução.

Então tenho as minhas classes declaradas com propriedades não anuláveis, vou utilizar um exemplo qualquer aqui:

```cs
class User
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";

    [JsonPropertyName("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Nessa classe eu espero que as propriedades `Name` e `Email` nunca sejam `null`, mas se eu receber um *JSON* no formato `{"name": null, "email": null}`, e desserializa-lo numa instancia dessa classe com a biblioteca *System.Text.Json*, eu terei um user com nome e email iguais a `null`.

Gostaria de saber o que pode ser feito para impedir esse tipo de comportamento. Até então pensei em implementar todos os *getters* e *setters* manualmente para impedir que recebam `null`, no seguinte estilo:

```cs
class User
{
    private string name = "";
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value ?? ""; }
    }

    private string email = "";
    [JsonPropertyName("email")]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value ?? ""; }
    }
}
```

Mas isso me parece desnecessariamente verboso e repetitivo. Gostaria de saber se existe uma abordagem padrão mais prática para esse problema.

Comment: o comportamento que você exemplificou é esse mesmo, o que você pode fazer é um tipo próprio para fazer esse aspecto para você, tem que dar uma olhada na biblioteca nessa parte

Comment: talvez a solução: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#exclude-all-null-value-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem a configuração para ignorar valores `null` como descrito na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#exclude-all-null-value-properties):

***Exemplo:***

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    IgnoreNullValues = true,
    WriteIndented = true
};
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast, options);
```

então na sua classe inicia com algum valor e com essa configuração vai ter o comportamento esperado.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Excluir propriedades da serialização](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#exclude-properties-from-serialization)
- [Excluir todas as propriedades de valor nulo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#exclude-all-null-value-properties)
- [JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues Propriedade](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.ignorenullvalues?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_IgnoreNullValues)

Comment: Isso resolve o problema com a desserialização, pena que as propriedades ainda ficam vulneráveis a outras bibliotecas, e a devs que não estão cientes desse comportamento.

Comment: Olha eu também acionaria ai uma validação @Júlio. Eu criticaria ainda mais os valores passados. Apesar que eu vulnerável a outras bibliotecas não entendi.